# Save page data after GET request?

Tags: javascript, django, get

Here is a GIF explaining the problem.

Queries to the database are made with GET requests.

When I make a GET request to pull additional data, all the checkboxes get unchecked.

How can I save the checkbox state (session data, local storage) after those GET requests?

I only need to hold onto those values in between queries. Once the user clicks "send to cartography" those checkbox values can be thrown away.

[image]

Comment: Please post a [mre] a GIF although may _show_ the problem it does not help people _reproduce_ it.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I'm not sure how to make a reproducible example without posting an entire application. Any tips? I'm willing to help get this answered in any way I can.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you wouldn't want to, because then states would be different in different browsers.  You'll always want to sync with the database at every page load.

Comment: This is just temporary until the user clicks "submit." Just something to hold the checkbox values after they modify the search. Nothing needs to persist after that.

Comment: Sounds like you aren't actually doing a GET request, sounds like your submitting a form.  A get request from javascript wouldn't reset the page or form field values.  Make sure your submit button is set to type "button" and not "submit" and use javascript to do the fetch.